# How do I make class methods / properties in Swift?

Tags: swift

Class (or static) methods in Objective-C were accomplished using `+` in declarations.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

+ (void)aClassMethod;
- (void)anInstanceMethod;

@end
```

How can this be achieved in Swift?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

They are called [**type properties**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_396) and [**type methods**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH15-XID_307) and you use the `class` or `static` keywords.

```
class Foo {
    var name: String?           // instance property
    static var all = [Foo]()    // static type property
    class var comp: Int {       // computed type property
        return 42
    }

    class func alert() {        // type method
        print("There are \(all.count) foos")
    }
}

Foo.alert()       // There are 0 foos
let f = Foo()
Foo.all.append(f)
Foo.alert()       // There are 1 foos
```

Comment: I don't think it's limited to Playground, it doesn't compile in an app either.

Comment: @ErikKerber Good to know, didn't yet need them so haven't tested myself, thanks.

Comment: Xcode 6.2 still reports 'class variables not yet supported' against anything of the form 'class var varName:Type'.

Comment: In Swift 2.0+, you don't need the `class` keyword before a function or a computed type property.

Answer (score 21):

They are called type properties and type methods in Swift and you use the class keyword.
Declaring a class method or Type method in swift :

```
class SomeClass 
{
     class func someTypeMethod() 
     {
          // type method implementation goes here
     }
}
```

Accessing that method :

```
SomeClass.someTypeMethod()
```

or you can refer [Methods in swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! Its even easier than an NSObject class in Objective-C and that was already pretty easy to setup.

Answer (score 16):

Prepend the declaration with `class` if it's a class, or with `static` if it's a structure.

```
class MyClass : {

    class func aClassMethod() { ... }
    func anInstanceMethod()  { ... }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need the `func` keyword here?

Comment: of course. Serves me for answering questions while standing on a crowded bus, lol. Corrected.

Comment: concise answer.  One of the overlooked aspects of a generation of Objective-C code that might not have been ported is that the next person may have to port it over to some version of Swift.  This is helpful as I'd completely forgotten about the notion of class methods from Obj-C, and I am in the midst of porting some mess.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 1.1 doesn't have stored class properties. You can implement it using a closure class property that fetches an associated object tied to the class object. (Only works in classes derived from NSObject.)

```
private var fooPropertyKey: Int = 0  // value is unimportant; we use var's address

class YourClass: SomeSubclassOfNSObject {

    class var foo: FooType? {  // Swift 1.1 doesn't have stored class properties; change when supported
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &fooPropertyKey) as FooType?
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &fooPropertyKey, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: I have been learning Swift and wondered if you could attach associated objects to Swift class instances. It sounds like the answer is "sort of". (Yes, but only objects that are a subclass of NSObject.) Thanks for resolving that for me. (Voted)

Answer (score 4):

Prepend the declaration with class or static if it's a function, or with static if it's a property.

```
class MyClass {

    class func aClassMethod() { ... }
    static func anInstanceMethod()  { ... }
    static var myArray : [String] = []
}
```