# Calling function from another scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my GameViewController i have this function:

```
 func shareButton(){
  var myShare = "test"
    let activityVC:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myShare], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion:nil)
 }
```

I Want to call this function from my GameScene, I tried it like this but it won't work:

```
GameViewController.shareButton()
```

This gives the error: "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call"

What is the proper way to make this work?

Comment: Sounds like `GameViewController` is not an instance of GameViewController but rather the class. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087936/how-do-i-make-class-methods-properties-in-swift

Comment: I tried to change func shareButton() into class func shareButton() but that also doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

In your game scene you can create a variable like this:

```
var gameViewController = GameViewController()
```

And then type this:

```
gameViewController.shareButton()
```

Comment: ok I got it thank you. and is my shareButton function good? because app crashes when this function starts(lldb error)

Comment: Does it show your app delegate with a green breakpoint line above the debugger? If it does what does the right side of the green line say?

Comment: Can you please see my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27621157/sharing-highscore-with-social-media