# Swift equivalent of static Objective-C expression

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

What is the Swift equivalent of the following expression:

```
static CGRect MYScaleRect(CGRect rect, CGFloat scale)
{
    return CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * scale, rect.origin.y * scale, rect.size.width * scale, rect.size.height * scale);
}
```

Comment: See [Type Methods section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html) on Swift documentation.

Comment: if I remember correctly in swift its called class not static (so class func foo not static func foo). See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087936/how-do-i-make-class-methods-properties-in-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of function (utility) I would recommend using the struct extension, but there are three ways.

**Free function:** (equivalent of the function from the question)

```
private func MYScaleRect(rect: CGRect , scale: CGFloat ) -> CGRect {
    return CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * scale, rect.origin.y * scale, rect.size.width * scale, rect.size.height * scale)
}
```

**Struct extension:**

```
private extension CGRect {
    static func MYScaleRect(rect: CGRect , scale: CGFloat ) -> CGRect {
        return CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * scale, rect.origin.y * scale, rect.size.width * scale, rect.size.height * scale)
    }
}
```

**Class method:**

```
private class func MYScaleRect(rect: CGRect , scale: CGFloat ) -> CGRect {
    return CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * scale, rect.origin.y * scale, rect.size.width * scale, rect.size.height * scale)
}
```

For this type of function (utility) I would recommend using the extension.

Comment: This answer does not describe the *equivalent* of the code in the question. It proposes two ways to **expose** the function instead of hiding it, as the original code does.

Comment: You are right, I have added all possibilities to the answer to let the reader decide what he needs.

Comment: Regarding your proposals to use a more language conforming solution: An extension on the struct seems reasonable. I don't see why you are proposing a type method, though. You would rather use a normal instance method. The second proposal "Class method" does not make sense at all. In which class would you put this method? And why?

Comment: Class method doesn't make sense to me in this context too, as it obfuscates the purpose of the method and hides possibility of the code reuse. It's in my answer only to present the language feature.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is plain C; there's no Objective-C involved. Also, strictly speaking, it is not an expression.

It is the definition of a function for which no symbol is emitted (that's what `static` does in this context). So the function is only visible in the current compilation unit (the .c or .m file where it's defined). The function is not tied to some class.

The semantic Swift equivalent would be a plain swift function with the `private` access modifier.

Answer (score 0):

If your method belongs to a class, in Swiftyou can use [type method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html):

```
class func MYScaleRect(rect: CGRect , scale: CGFloat )-> CGRect {}
```

> Instance methods, as described above, are methods that are called on
>   an instance of a particular type. You can also define methods that are
>   called on the type itself. These kinds of methods are called type
>   methods. You indicate type methods for classes by writing the keyword
>   class before the method’s func keyword, and type methods for
>   structures and enumerations by writing the keyword static before the
>   method’s func keyword.

Comment: No. A type method is still a method. The question's code just contains a plain function.