# Why do we need a weakSelf for functions/methods within closures?

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, closures

Reading [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40530556/5175709). 
I fully understand why we need a weakSelf for members/properties. They could create memory cycles. But properties have a memory location.
Do functions also have memory locations?! I mean isn't a function something just happens on the go? If so is the memory location type any different from a property location?

If I don't refer using self I get this error.

> Call to method 'alertFunc' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to
>   make capture semantics explicit

which is slightly different from:

> Reference to property 'window' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to
>   make capture semantics explicit

My code is as follows:

```
let another = UIAlertAction(title: "Log", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default){action in  
 logAction ()

 }

private func logAction () {

print("health")

}
```

Comment: Functions are first-class Types in Swift. Obviously they're semantically different, but practically speaking functions can be though of as simply a different kind of variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>credit to iOS nerds I know from a meetup</sub>

tl;dr you need to use self for **instance** methods, but don't need it for **class** methods. A class may have many instances, but it can only have one declaration of itself (which also contains its type/class/static functions).

**Why error occurs 1:** Bare in mind the `alertFunc` could have had a reference to a property.

It could have been :

```
private func logAction () {

    print("someProperty = \(self.someProperty)")

}
```

So, in this case it's obvious that you are eventually referencing a property.

---

**Why error occurs 2:** Even if you don't have a reference to `self` within your function, still because you wrote it as an instance method, the self is *implicitly* passed on. But, we don't see!

An instance method is really just syntactic sugar for a function that takes an instance for the first parameter, which is self passed automatically.

Under the hood it may look *something* like this :

```
private func alertFunc (_ instance: MyType) {

    print("someProperty = \(instance.someProperty)")

}

// and actually the call to it *may* look something like this:

MyType.someFunc(self)
```

We never see the self being passed! It's a syntactic sugar that deceives us.

So, if your method does not use self internally (i.e. doesn't rely on the state of the instance in any way) then it's actually probably best to make it a [static/type/class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087936/how-do-i-make-class-methods-properties-in-swift) or free function.

---

**Alternative1:** use a free function.

```
class someClass {

    ...

}

func freeFunc {
    print("Hi this is a free function, written outside the scope of any class...")
}
```

And then within your closure you call it using `freeFunc()`

**Alternative2:** Use a class function.

```
class someClass {

    ...

     class private func alertFunc() {
          print("Hi this was a class function, see the class at the beginning of the func definition")
     }
 }
```

And then within your closure you call it using `yourClassName.alertFunc()`

---

But, why is it that class functions don't create memory cycles but instance functions do?
 I'm glad you asked:

For instance mehtods, for each instance that you reach out to, there is a **new** memory location and generate a **new** memory cycle which would persist deallocations.

For class methods, for each time you reach out to the class/type methods you reach out to the **same** class/type method, and while you persist that class method, you won't be creating it over and over, it is only created once and done!

In objective-C (and C++) type methods:

When the app starts up, the system can fairly safely just pre-allocate ALL the instructions
 for those type methods into memory along with their class pointers
 so there’s little to no overhead calling those over and over and over  again.
I imagine swift is doing the same thing

Comment: So from that. It's better to use static/class functions rather than normal functions then? (Memory allocation wise)

Comment: So if I call a function inside a class over and over it just makes more and more instances of itself? But what if it's just changing s value inside the class? (Sorry I'm kind of s newbie in the topic of memory allocation)

Comment: @ZonilyJame *So from that. It's better to use static/class functions rather than normal functions then* <-- for a moment forget the memory allocation issue. And only think about the *purpose* of the function. Do you fully understand why we have a type/class method vs instance method?

Comment: @ZonilyJame, no, new instances are not created when you call methods. It's still the same object.

Comment: I use class/static methods whrn I'm always using the same function over the whole project.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `logAction()`, it implicitly means `self.logAction()`. (Methods are called on some instance; when you don't specify, it defaults to `self`.) So you are using `self` inside the closure, which means the closure captures `self`, and whether it captures a strong or weak reference has memory management implications.